# Доступные методы в зависимости от конструктора C#

Tags: c#, классы, методы

Возможно ли менять доступные методы в зависимости от конструктора?
К примеру, есть класс `Data` с двумя конструкторами: `Data(String ID)` и
`Data(String ID,Int32 Number)` и методами `Create()`, `Delete()`, `Count()`.

Необходимо:

Если создается экземпляр класса `Data Data1 = new Data("123");`, то доступны будут лишь методы `Create()` и `Delete()`. Если же экземпляр класса `Data Data2 = new Data("123",123);`, то доступны все 3 метода: `Create()`, `Delete()` и `Count()`.
Заранее всем спасибо за помощь и потраченное время.

Comment: Передавайте на конструктор переменную IsCreateEnabled и какие ещё нужны, сохраняйте, проверяйте в методе. И кстати, в текущем виде ваш класс нарушает Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Ну даже не так, а просто в конструкторе выставлять эту переменную. Но вообще выглядит как-то не очень такой дизайн. Возможно, лучше отнаследовать класс от базового и добавить ему функционала

Comment: Вариант с наследованием (как в ответе) прекрасно работает в компайл-тайме, но нужны два класса. Вариант с переменной/полем замечательно работает в рантайме (и класс всего один), но нет помощи в процессе написания кода. Третий вариант: можно обойтись всего одним классом без наследования и получить подсказки в IDE: для этого нужно написать анализатор roslyn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ООП - наследование.

```cs
public class Data
{
    public Data(string id)
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        //...
    }

    // ...
}

public class DataItem : Data
{
    public DataItem(string id, int number) : base(id)
    {
        //...
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        //...
    }

    // ...
}
```

```cs
Data data1 = new Data("123");
DataItem data2 = new DataItem("123", 123);

List<Data> items = new List<Data>();
items.Add(data1);
items.Add(data2); // без наследования такое бы не сработало
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)